# Searching a custom linked list - Which is the better method?

Tags: java, linked-list

So I have two implementation of a method that searches a custom linked list with `name` as input and either gets the `mark` associated with the `name` if the name is found or returns `-1`.

```
public int getMark (String name) {
    Node p = head;
    while ((p != null) && !(p.getName().equals(name)){
        p = p.getNext();
    }

    if (p == null){
      return - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      return p.getMark();
    }
}
```

OR

```
public int getMark(String name){
    Node p = head;

    if(head == null)
    {
      return -1;
      break;
    }

    while(p != null)
    {
        if(p.getName().equals(name)
        {
            return p.getMark();
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
        p = p.getNext();
    }
}
```

They both do the job but I want to know which solution is better. I personally find the first solution confusing and not logically sound.

Comment: Are you sure that the 2nd does the job?

Comment: With some thought, the second one can be fixed so that it is as readable as the first one. Then it doesn't matter which one you choose. By the way, decide whether you want the `{` on the same line or a new line. Whichever you choose, be consistent.

Comment: 2nd one doesn't compile; it does not return any value if the list is empty.

Comment: @KCWong I've updated the second one with an if condition that checks for the empty list. Does it seem correct now?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I've updated it, please have a look.

Comment: Still second logic is not proper, even you can't write break statement after return, also it will return -1 on first node if it will not mtch

Comment: IMO, while statements are evil because they are hard to read and are sometimes source of infinite loop. It would be more readable with `for(Node p = head; p != null && !p.getName().equals(name); p = p.getNext())`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle for loops are indeed sometimes preferable, but you need to declare Node p outside of the loop because you'll need to use p afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is not seems better as if any of your node may be null then it will return -1 and not check further,

Also your second logic is little bit complex it should be as below which can perform better.

```
 public int getMark(String name){
    Node p = head;

    if(head == null)
    {
      return -1;
    }

    while(p != null)
    {
        if(p.getName().equals(name)
        {
            return p.getMark();
        }
        p = p.getNext();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Aha I see where I made it unnecessarily complicated. This makes perfect sense.

Comment: Enjoy Your Coding

Comment: No need for that `head == null` check at all. Just remove the whole if block.

Answer (score 0):

Your second version won't work unless the head contains the correct one and the first version seems a bit too much. Have a look at this: It's faster and (in my opinion) more readable

```
public int getMark (String name) {
    Node p = head;

    //Check if head is the correct one
    if (name.equals(p.getName())){
        return p.getMark();
    }

    while (hasNext(p)){
        p = p.getNext();

        if (name.equals(p.getName())){
            return p.getMark();
        }
    }

    //Ending up here means we didn't find it
    return -1;
 }

private boolean hasNext(Node p){
    return p.getNext() != null;
}
```

Note that I'm assuming `head` and 'name' are not null, otherwise this won't work of course

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach as it's concise and readable (in my opinion). Pretty much a variation of your first implementation. Arguably you could return -1 if the head is null.

```
public int getMark(String name) {
    Node p = head;
    while (p != null && !p.getName().equals(name)) {
        p = p.next;
    }
    return p != null ? p.getMark() : -1;
}
```